# No Default Icon for Edit Application Menu Bash Script When Dropped to Empty Panel

Tags: kde, 15.10

When dragging an Application to an open space in a Panel, The application Icon for that app is visible and placed in the panel. When I create an Entry for a Bash Script using Edit Application Menu and drop this into a Panel, no Default Icon is used and the entry in the Panel is invisible. If I hover my mouse over the Panel area where I expect the entry to be, a Popup shows the name of the Entry. Is this an error or does the current design of KDE not Support using a default Icon to represent these types of entries?